# File splitter method goes wrong when working with decimals

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, byte, filestream

I'm trying to develop a file-splitter method that splits a file into chunks of the desired size, it works perfect for files that has even filesize values (*eg: if filesize is **2097152** bytes and I want to split it into two chunks, first chunk is **1048576** bytes and second chunk is **1048576** bytes*),

the problem is when I try to split a file that when I divide its filesize it has decimals, for example I want to split a file of **8194321** bytes in two (or whatever) chunks, the half filesize is **4097160,5** bytes but as I need to use integers then I set chunk size to **4097161** bytes to create two chunks, the first chunk of **4097161** bytes and the second chunk of **4097160** bytes, but when I try split the file, when working the last chunk I get a `System.ArgumentException` exception on this instruction:

```
outputStream.Write(buffer, bufferLength * bufferCount, tmpBufferLength)
```

with this error message:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater
>   than the number of elements from index to the end of the source
>   collection.

How I can fix my file-splitter method to properly split a file which has decimals when divided?

This is an usage example:

```
Split(sourceFile:=Me.fileToSplit,
      chunkSize:=CInt(New FileInfo(fileToSplit).Length / 2),
      chunkName:="File.Part",
      chunkExt:="fs")
```

This the relevant code of the file-splitter procedure:

```
''' <summary>
''' Splits a file into manageable chunks.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sourceFile">The file to split.</param>
''' <param name="chunkSize">The size per chunk.</param>
''' <param name="chunkName">The name formatting for chunks.</param>
''' <param name="chunkExt">The file-extension for chunks.</param>
Public Sub Split(ByVal sourceFile As String,
                 ByVal chunkSize As Integer,
                 ByVal chunkName As String,
                 ByVal chunkExt As String)

    ' FileInfo instance of the source file.
    Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(sourceFile)

    ' The total filesize to split, in bytes.
    Dim totalSize As Long = fInfo.Length

    ' The remaining size to calculate the percentage, in bytes.
    Dim sizeRemaining As Long = totalSize

    ' Counts the length of the current chunk file to calculate the percentage, in bytes.
    Dim sizeWritten As Long = 0L

    ' The buffer to read data and write the chunks.
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte() {}

    ' The buffer length.
    Dim bufferLength As Integer = 524288 ' 512 Kb

    ' The total amount of chunks to create.
    Dim chunkCount As Long = CLng(Math.Ceiling((fInfo.Length - bufferLength) / (chunkSize)))

    ' Keeps track of the current chunk.
    Dim chunkIndex As Long = 0L

    ' A zero-filled string to enumerate the chunk parts.
    Dim enumeration As String = String.Empty

    ' The chunks filename.
    Dim chunkFilename As String = String.Empty

    ' Open the file to start reading bytes.
    Using inputStream As New FileStream(fInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open)

        Using binaryReader As New BinaryReader(inputStream)

            While (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)

                chunkIndex += 1L 'Increment the chunk file counter.

                ' Set chunk filename.
                enumeration = New String("0"c, CStr(chunkCount).Length - CStr(chunkIndex).Length)
                chunkFilename = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", chunkName, enumeration & CStr(chunkIndex), chunkExt)

                ' Reset written byte-length counter.
                sizeWritten = 0L

                ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
                Using outputStream As New FileStream(chunkFilename, FileMode.Create)

                    ' Read until reached the end-bytes of the input file.
                    While (sizeWritten < chunkSize) AndAlso (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)

                        ' Read bytes from the source file.
                        buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(chunkSize)

                        Dim bufferCount As Integer = 0
                        Dim tmpBufferLength As Integer = bufferLength

                        While (sizeWritten < chunkSize)

                            If (bufferLength + (bufferLength * bufferCount)) >= chunkSize Then
                                tmpBufferLength = chunkSize - ((bufferLength * bufferCount))
                            End If

                            ' Write those bytes in the chunk file.
                            outputStream.Write(buffer, bufferLength * bufferCount, tmpBufferLength)

                            bufferCount += 1

                            ' Increment the bytes-written counter.
                            sizeWritten += tmpBufferLength

                            ' Decrease the bytes-remaining counter.
                            sizeRemaining -= tmpBufferLength

                            ' Reset the temporal buffer length.
                            tmpBufferLength = bufferLength

                        End While

                    End While ' (sizeWritten < chunkSize) AndAlso (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)

                    outputStream.Flush()

                End Using ' outputStream

            End While ' inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length

        End Using ' binaryReader

    End Using ' inputStream

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the `While (sizeWritten < chunkSize)` block is because inside that block I trigger some events, instead of writting the entire buffer at once I use that while loop to "slowly" write the other buffer, this way I split files at exact size except for files with filesize that when divided has decimals, then throws that exception I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the right amount to read before actually reading. Right now, you always read `chunkSize` bytes but you are sometimes discarding the tail of that buffer.

I think the intention is that `tmpBufferLength` has the correct buffer length. Assuming that works out (which I am too lazy to verify...) read exactly that amount from the source and then write the entire buffer to the destination.

Comment: `tmpBufferLength` intention is to set the correct buffer length when writting the last chunk, it works perfect (I think) except for filesizes that when divisable it has decimals.

Comment: Good. Then simply read this amount instead of reading chunkSize. What do you think about that?

Comment: That does not work (same exception) or I'm applying bad

Comment: I think you're "applying bad". I have no way to help you further without seeing the new code. Also, did you try to debug the code?

Comment: `I have no way to help you further without seeing the new code` From the beginning I published a functional code that everyone could test to try split a file and see what exception happens. I know the code is missing or not working good some bytes on that ciscunstances, the thing Is I need help to properly fix that problem. Yes I debugged it without succes, some breakpoints, some analysis of the autos, Im in the same point. thanks for comment.

Comment: Do you understand that the way your code is right now has no chance of working? See my answer for why that is and for a potential solution. I will not write the code for you but I'll help you get this done if you post new code that no longer has the problem that I described. Maybe there is another problem and maybe I'll be able to spot it.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to help illustrating a code neither a pseudo-code, then at least could you specify step by step where you seen I'm commiting a misstep and how I could fix it?, You've said I'm discarding the tail, but how to do it then?. Because If I publish a question of a code that does not works as expected is to get help, not to hear that the code is not working. thanks anyways, sincerelly.

Comment: I totally disagree with this kind of help because really this is not help, but this is the only answer that I can accept because it is approximated to the problem description and some "hints" of the problem resolution on the OP side. Well, after some days refactoring the code I finally managed to solve it by calculating right the chunk size, just Maths always messed me. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler version that should do what you want with no chunk size drama. This code was witten in C# and converted to VB using this tool:
http://converter.telerik.com/

```
Public Sub Split(sourceFile As String,
                 chunkSize As Integer,
                 chunkName As String,
                 chunkExt As String)
    Using source As New FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(8192) {}
        Dim chunkIndex As Integer = 0

        While source.Position < source.Length
            chunkIndex += 1

            Using chunk As New FileStream(String.Format("{0}.{1:0000}.{2}", chunkName, chunkIndex, chunkExt), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
                While source.Position < source.Length AndAlso chunk.Position < CLng(chunkSize)
                    Dim len As Integer = Math.Min(buffer.Length, Math.Min(chunkSize, CInt(source.Length - source.Position)))

                    len = source.Read(buffer, 0, len)
                    chunk.Write(buffer, 0, len)
                End While
            End Using
        End While
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks anyways but the approach that you've provided does not splits a file at exact size, which is what I'm trying to do. For example using that code if I split a file of 6 Mb (6291456 bytes) into two files, the first chunk is greather (3146112 bytes) than the second chunk (3145344 bytes), i suppose this is because the buffer difference, then basically using your code I'll have exact the same problem to fix as in my own approach above.

Comment: Actually my code above splits at exact size, except for files that has filesize that when divided has decimals, as I explained, then is thrown that exception. PS: Don't need to worry about translating C# to Vb.Net to answer in this question, I could manage a working C# approach too if you preffer.

Comment: You are really not being very clear. Are you trying to figure out how to write file chunks, or are you trying to figure out how to determine chunk size? If it's the latter, then it's just simple integer math and all this file stuff is clouding the issue. Once you figure out chunk size, my code above will do the job without issue. Try chunkSize = FileSize / ChunkCount + FileSize % ChunkCount.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I will share my solution to Split files at exact size:

(event-usage code need to be stripped from this code)

```
''' <summary>
''' Splits a file into manageable chunks, or merge the splitted chunks. 
''' With progress-percent features.
''' </summary>
Public NotInheritable Class FileSplitter

...

''' <summary>
''' Gets or sets the buffer-size used to split or merge, in Bytes.
''' Default value is: 524288 bytes (512 Kb).
''' </summary>
''' <value>The buffer-size.</value>
Public Property BufferSize As Integer = 524288
'    4096 Bytes (  4 Kb) This is the default Microsoft's FileStream implementation buffer size.
'    8192 Bytes (  8 Kb)
'   16384 Bytes ( 16 Kb)
'   32768 Bytes ( 32 Kb)
'   65536 Bytes ( 64 Kb)
'  131072 Bytes (128 Kb)
'  262144 Bytes (256 Kb)
'  524288 Bytes (512 Kb)
' 1048576 Bytes (  1 Mb)

''' <summary>
''' Splits a file into manageable chunks.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="sourceFile">The file to split.</param>
''' <param name="chunkSize">The size per chunk.</param>
''' <param name="chunkName">The name formatting for chunks.</param>
''' <param name="chunkExt">The file-extension for chunks.</param>
''' <param name="overwrite">If set to <c>True</c>, any existing file will be overwritten if needed to create a chunk, otherwise, an exception will be thrown.</param>
''' <param name="deleteAfterSplit">If set to <c>True</c>, the input file will be deleted after a successful split operation.</param>
''' <exception cref="System.IO.FileNotFoundException">The specified source file doesn't exists.</exception>
''' <exception cref="System.IO.IOException">File already exists.</exception>
''' <exception cref="System.OverflowException">'chunkSize' value should be smaller than the source filesize.</exception>
Public Sub Split(ByVal sourceFile As String,
                 ByVal chunkSize As Long,
                 Optional ByVal chunkName As String = Nothing,
                 Optional ByVal chunkExt As String = Nothing,
                 Optional ByVal overwrite As Boolean = False,
                 Optional ByVal deleteAfterSplit As Boolean = False)

    If Not File.Exists(sourceFile) Then
        Throw New FileNotFoundException("The specified source file doesn't exists.", sourceFile)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' FileInfo instance of the source file.
    Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(sourceFile)

    ' The total filesize to split, in bytes.
    Dim totalSize As Long = fInfo.Length

    ' The remaining size to calculate the percentage, in bytes.
    Dim sizeRemaining As Long = totalSize

    ' Counts the length of the current chunk file to calculate the percentage, in bytes.
    Dim sizeWritten As Long

    ' The buffer to read data and write the chunks.
    Dim buffer As Byte()

    ' The buffer length.
    Dim bufferLength As Integer

    ' The total amount of chunks to create.
    Dim chunkCount As Long = CLng(Math.Ceiling((fInfo.Length) / (chunkSize)))

    ' Keeps track of the current chunk.
    Dim chunkIndex As Long

    ' Keeps track of the amount of buffer-writting operations.
    Dim writeCounts As Integer

    ' Keeps track of the current buffer-writting operation.
    Dim writeCount As Integer

    ' A zero-filled string to enumerate the chunk parts.
    Dim fileEnumeration As String

    ' The chunks filename.
    Dim chunkFilename As String

    ' The chunks basename.
    chunkName = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(chunkName),
                   Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fInfo.Name)),
                   Path.Combine(fInfo.DirectoryName, chunkName))

    ' The chunks file extension.
    chunkExt = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(chunkExt),
                  fInfo.Extension.Substring(1),
                  chunkExt)

    Select Case chunkSize ' Set buffer size and calculate chunk count.

        Case Is >= fInfo.Length ' chunk size is bigger than source-file size.
            Throw New OverflowException("'chunkSize' value should be smaller than the source filesize.")
            Exit Sub

        Case Is < Me.BufferSize ' chunk size is smaller than buffer size.
            bufferLength = CInt(chunkSize)

        Case Else ' chunk size is bigger than buffer size.
            bufferLength = Me.BufferSize

    End Select ' chunkSize

    If Not overwrite Then ' If not file overwriting is allowed then...

        For index As Long = 1L To chunkCount ' Start index based on 1 (eg. "File.Part.1.ext").

            ' Set chunk filename.
            fileEnumeration = New String("0"c, CStr(chunkCount).Length - CStr(index).Length)
            chunkFilename = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", chunkName, fileEnumeration & CStr(index), chunkExt)

            ' If chunk file already exists then...
            If File.Exists(chunkFilename) Then
                Throw New IOException(String.Format("File already exists: {0}", chunkFilename))
                Exit Sub
            End If

        Next index

    End If ' overwrite

    ' Open the file to start reading bytes.
    Using inputStream As New FileStream(fInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open)

        Using binaryReader As New BinaryReader(inputStream)

            While (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)

                ' Increment the chunk file counter.
                chunkIndex += 1L

                ' Set chunk filename.
                fileEnumeration = New String("0"c, CStr(chunkCount).Length - CStr(chunkIndex).Length)
                chunkFilename = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", chunkName, fileEnumeration & CStr(chunkIndex), chunkExt)

                ' Reset written byte-length counter.
                sizeWritten = 0L

                ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
                Using outputStream As New FileStream(chunkFilename, FileMode.Create)

                    ' Calculate the amount of buffer-writting operations.
                    writeCounts = CInt(Math.Ceiling(chunkSize / bufferLength))
                    writeCount = 0

                    ' Read until reached the end-bytes of the input file.
                    While (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length) AndAlso (sizeWritten < chunkSize)

                        ' Increment the buffer-writting counter.
                        writeCount += 1

                        ' If buffer-writting operation is the last buffer-writting operation then...
                        If (writeCount = writeCounts) Then
                            ' Fix buffer size for writting the last buffer-data.
                            bufferLength = CInt(chunkSize - sizeWritten)
                        End If

                        ' Read bytes from the input file).
                        buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(bufferLength)

                        ' Write those bytes in the chunk file.
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

                        ' Increment the bytes-written counter.
                        sizeWritten += buffer.Length

                        ' Decrease the bytes-remaining counter.
                        sizeRemaining -= buffer.Length

                    End While ' (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length) AndAlso (sizeWritten < chunkSize)

                    outputStream.Flush()

                End Using ' outputStream

            End While ' (inputStream.Position < inputStream.Length)

        End Using ' binaryReader

    End Using ' inputStream

End Sub

...

End Class
```